# problem with haxelib when installing a library

Tags: haxe, haxelib

I am trying to install a library, but it always returns this.

```
Error: std@date_set_day
```

I have not yet been able to find a solution to this strange error. it works fine on **Windows**, but I have this problem on **Gnu/Linux**.

This is to compile the **Friday Night Funkin**.

Comment: Please show the command you are using to try to install the library. Please describe how you installed Haxe. Give more context if possible. More information might help us suggest things to try!

Comment: For some reason I get this error when I use the correct time and time zone with my country.

I am using Europe/Madrid time zone.

and it already let me download and install the libraries.

Comment: What time zone causes it to fail? If this can be reproduced by just setting the timezone, it could be reported as a bug to haxe or some library and they might be able to fix and improve Haxe as a result.